# puppeteer trigger ajax and get response data

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I need to get what comes in response to an ajax request after clicking on a div
Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Js test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pt = 'dc37ecab5ca7675be79857f3657b773';
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #button{
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background: yellow;
            width: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 2;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Title text</h1>
    <div id="button">
        <div>get data</div>
        <div id="result">*******</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#button').click(function(){ 
        $.ajax({
          url: "ajax.php",
          data: {pt: pt},
          success: function(data){
            $('#button').addClass('activated');
            $('#result').text(data);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['pt']) && !empty($_GET['pt']) && $_GET['pt'] == 'dc37ecab5ca7675be79857f3657b773'){
    echo 'success';
}else{
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

When a button is pressed, a request is made the result of which is inserted into the result block, and a class 'activated' is added to the button block.
Next, I try to trigger this click through the puppeteer.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async() => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const pageURL = 'http://puppeteer.local';

  try {
    await page.goto(pageURL);
    console.log(`Page open: ${pageURL}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Can not open page: ${pageURL} error: ${error}`);
  }


    const titleSelector = 'h1';         
    await page.waitForSelector(titleSelector);         
    const pageTitle = await page.$eval(
      titleSelector, titleSelector => titleSelector.outerHTML
    );
    console.log('title: ', pageTitle);            

    const buttonSelector = '#button';  
    await page.waitForSelector(buttonSelector, { timeout: 0 });

    await Promise.all([
        //page.waitForNavigation(), 
        page.click(buttonSelector), 
    ]);

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

    const buttonSelectorReuslt = '#button.activated #result'; 
    await page.waitForSelector(buttonSelectorReuslt, { timeout: 5000 });
    const buttonResult = await page.$eval(buttonSelectorReuslt, 
      buttonSelectorReuslt => buttonSelectorReuslt.innerHTML);         
    console.log('result: ', buttonResult);

  await browser.close();

  process.exit()
})();
```

I see in the console

```
node .\index.js
Page open: http://puppeteer.local
title:  <h1>Title text</h1>
result: success
```

Is it possible to somehow force the puppeteer to initialize the request on his own without pressing a button.
We need to do this GET request to the url with the parameter
http://puppeteer.local/ajax.php?pt=dc37ecab5ca7675be79857f3657b773
and get response.

**and second question**
How can I perform any action immediately after the end of the ajax request, now I'm just doing a delay of 3 seconds
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

And I would like to somehow find out that the ajax request has been completed and immediately after that do the remaining actions, such as searching for updated tags, or parsing what returned this request
In other words, something like a handler of the received response, rather than doing this delay in the execution of the code for 3 seconds

Comment: You don't have to use puppeteer to do that. Maybe you can use `request` or `request-promise` packages from the npm.

Comment: The purpose of the question is to force the headless browser to execute such a request.

Comment: Well i don't know the method you're asking. But AFAIK, puppeteer cannot request by itself without any on page handler event like click button.

Maybe you can make the button with page.evaluate and request to the server eventually by clicking the button.

Comment: I read the documentation and undestand it is impossible to do. Thank for your help.